# unexpected whitespace handling in rythm removes wanted blanks

Tags: rythm

In the attempt to move from Freemarker to Rythm I am getting the effect that Rythm removes a lot of whitespace.

I am aware that there are @compact @nocompact and @escape options.I tried some of these but they seem to have no effect on the whitespace handling.
According to http://rythmengine.org/doc/configuration.md#codegen_compact_enabled
the default handling is compacting.

Rythm seems to remove whitespace that I actively try to insert e.g.

```
no whitespace here
@nocompact() {
  @for (int i=0;i<2;i++) {
    please keep the whitespace
  }
}
no whitespace here
```

will lead to

```
no whitespace here
 please keep the whitespace
please keep the whitespace
no whitespace here
```

effectively changing the whitespace to a single space.

**How can the original whitespace setting be kept?**

**Is the non functioning nocompact() a bug?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bug. Please fire an issue on https://github.com/greenlaw110/rythm/issues